# Command to compare speed of web-browsers

Tags: web

I was asked the following: Which one, Firefox or Chrome, downloads and renders the page https://unix.stackexchange.com/ faster. Is there a command in Linux to measure that?

Comment: Using the builtin developer toolbar within the browsers you can get the load time easily. Keep in mind that cache matters so open incognito windows and take several shots to get a more realistic average time. The rendering time can also be calculated that way. Explore it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no command in Linux to do this, I might be wrong, but I don't know of a freely available piece of software that does this.

In the past Toms Hardware used to do a regular "Browser Grand Prix", where they would compare all current versions of the most popular browsers available out there, but I think this may have stopped now, as looking at the site they don't appear to have published one recently. Anyway, they did put a lot of information about how they did their testing on one of their articles:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/web-browser-chrome-25-firefox-19,review-32650-3.html

On there they mention using this service:

http://www.eembc.org/benchmark/browsing_sl.php

Looking at that you cannot choose the sites that are loaded (without paying), but you could use that tool in each browser to get a fair representation of the rendering times for a range of sites, not just stack exchange, which is probably a better real world test than just one site. Unless you **need** to test stack, you can probably get away with using the free version:

http://bxbenchdemo.eembc.org/

Comment: Hmm. I guess it might be possible to find the time if you are sure for example that browsers can render the page in 10 seconds. Then you can use binary search and take screenshots to find the time when the page looks similar that after rendering it 10 seconds.